# I want to return true or false based on the element presence using Fluent wait, how to do that?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Fluent wait and I see that the return value of function is WebElement. However, I want to retun true or false based on the element's presence. How can I do it? I refer this page - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Code snipppet is here -

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

I tried changing to below, but it gives me error -

> The method until(Function) in the type
>   Wait is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   Function(){})

Here is what I changed -

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(retryCount, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        Boolean foo = wait.until(new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebElement by) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I am using Guava version 23.0, Selenium 3.0, Java 1.8.*

Comment: The WebElement object have methods such as  `.isVisible()`, `.isPresent()` methods which return a boolean value. Have you tried those yet?

Comment: isVisible() is not of use, because some of the elements are hidden in the DOM. I have never seen inbuilt isPresent() method in selenium.

Comment: Oh my mistake, `.isPresent()` is a method in the Serenity framework and not present in Selenium. So just to clarify, you're looking for a method that returns true for a web element which may not be visible in the viewport, but is present in the DOM?

Comment: I want to write a function which returns true if the element is present on the screen, no matter whether it is visible or hidden.

Comment: 'element is present on the screen' seems to suggest that the element should be visually seen within the viewport. 'no matter visible or hidden' suggests that you do not care if the element's `display` or `visibility` property is set to visible or hidden. Which do you refer to? Because an element may not be visually seen within the viewport, but exists as a html element with `display:none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only element visibility matters then try with following : -

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

     boolean status = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(By.name("q")).isDisplayed();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

findelements() is one easier way to check element presence

```
if(driver.findelements(By.id("foo")).size()>0) {
  //true
}
```